# Linux and compatibility between processors

Tags: linux, compilation, arm, embedded, atmel

I've inherited an embedded project that's been developed for two embedded systems: the [Glomation GESBC-9G20](http://www.glomationinc.com/products/index.php?n=SBC.GESBC-9G20) based off the Atmel AT91SAM9g20 and the [Acme Systems Aria G25](http://www.acmesystems.it/aria) based off the Atmel AT91SAM9g25. At the moment the project is built using stock compilers provided by the manufacturers of the different boards that implement these processors and the boards run different versions of the Linux kernel:

`uname -a` on the GESBC-9G20 gives `Linux 2.6.31.5 #10 Thu Nov 5 15:46:30 GMT 2009 armv5tejl GNU/Linux` 
`uname -a` on the Aria G25 gives `Linux ariag25 3.16.1 #1 Mon Oct 13 11:44:47 BST 2014 armv5tejl GNU/Linux`

The manufacturer provided tool-chains for each are not compatible, one uses EABI binaries the other does not.

I have done some research and found that the two micro-controllers both run ARM926EJ-S processor cores, however the G20 has 32KB of caches and the G25 has 16KB of caches according to datasheets [here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc6384.pdf) and [here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11032-32-bit-ARM926EJ-S-Microcontroller-SAM9G25_Datasheet.pdf) respectively. Would I be able to use the same tool-chain to build binaries for both of these micro-controllers? Would the difference in cache size affect binaries/kernels compiled for these processors?

Further to this, as the applications for the two systems share a large portion of their source code, I am interested in re-compiling the linux kernel and applications so that the two boards run the same version of the kernel and tool-chain. I think this would make development easier and would reduce the amount of extra work required in deploying to the systems. Am I right in thinking this?

Finally would the extra effort required to re-compile the kernels and re-build the tool chain be worth the effort in the long run? I appreciate that every situation might be different but given the information available (which is as much as I have at the moment as well) what would you choose?

To summarize:

1. Will the two micro-controllers based off the ARM926EJ-S with different cache sizes be cross-compatible?
2. Would re-building the tool-chain and kernel for these micro-controllers be beneficial and save development time in the future?
3. Given this information, would you choose to re-build the tool-chains and kernels or would you continue with the separate tool-chains available now?

Comment: What version of the Linux kernel are your boards running currently?

Comment: @RichardPennington I've updated the original question to include the output of uname -a on both boards.

Comment: I'm not sure what your application looks like, but one option might be just to build the user space stuff with a single tool chain and to leave the kernels intact. If you link your user space applications statically, they will likely run on both boards. Then you don't have to deal with the complications of upgrading the kernels but can get some benefit from a common tool chain.

Comment: These aren't *"micro-controllers"*; Atmel calls them MPUs.  The cache size differences are irrelevant codewise.  I would rebuild everything with one toolchain (optimized for ARM926ej-s) and a common code base.  The two boards can use the same Linux kernel image but boot with individual Device Tree blobs.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - Start with a merged Linux kernel and use OABI support.  See how that works and then contemplate merging user-space.

---

The way you have phrased this question makes it appear subjective.  In fact, just giving an answer would be.  Lets consider some facts.  First an answer will depend on your goals and certain organizational qualification.  Ie, there can be no completely correct answer for anyone.  But if we examine the benefits and disadvantages, things should be clear for most.

---

> Will the two micro-controllers based off the ARM926EJ-S with different cache sizes be cross-compatible?

For the code generation aspect of the compiler, these are almost certainly 100% identical.  Ie, a gcc should have no trouble generating code for one or the other.  However, there are larger issues with changing a compiler,

1. Code relying on undefined behavior may not work.
2. Code using compiler *extensions* will need porting.
3. Bugs in the compiler may have work-arounds in source or cause some latent defect when the compiler is updated.
4. Timing differences may expose race conditions in really bad drivers.

> Would re-building the tool-chain and kernel for these micro-controllers be beneficial and save development time in the future?

Of course, this depends.  *Linux 2.6.31.5* is not a **stable** kernel (Ie, it does not have community patches) unlike Linux 2.6.32.65.  If the vendor does not provide a *git* tree, it is <strike>impossible</strike> difficult to tell what has/has not been applied to this tree.  So supporting this older version of Linux is probably a large task.  Ie, security patches, sub-system updates, and general bugs.  If you need to support custom drivers on both platforms, a similar Linux API will be a definite win.  If you only use the vendor Linux kernels and have no competency to support/change them then this may slant the issue.

The 3.16 is a more modern Linux.  However, it will also not have community support.  3.14 or 3.18 are currently *long-term*.  Most certainly updating to 3.18 and taking vendor drivers/device tree from 3.16 is fairly simple task. So major Linux kernel question would be,

1. Do both *Vendor A* and *Vendor B* vigorously support the kernels?
2. How much custom code/drivers do they provide.
3. What are your in-house or external kernel competencies?
4. Do you have custom drivers your self?
5. Will you update the hardware to new chipsets in future.
6. Chipsets life expectancy.
7. Does the product use *iptables*, *usb*, etc. sub-systems within Linux?

In my experience the answer to 1 (for any vendor) is **NEVER**!.  The people supporting this are over-worked and the company will not give them time to do things properly.  Items 4-6 will point to merging the kernels.  Supporting things on multiple kernels is painful.  Not only for writing the code, but for testing.  It is also possible to have the same binary support both platforms which may bring other benefits.

As for the toolchain, you have issues in the first question to contend with for user-space.  However, the Linux kernels should work well with a variety of compilers.  There are various checks to see if the compiler is compatible.  Also, the modern Linux kernels support both OABI and EABI.  So it is completely possible to make the Linux kernel merged while keeping user-space separate.

> Given this information, would you choose to re-build the tool-chains and kernels or would you continue with the separate tool-chains available now?

This is an opinion as phrased now.  It is highly unlikely that the vendor support is as good the community.  However, if you have no experience with kernels and/or drivers **AND** you envision the hardware never changing, you might stick with the Linux kernels provided.  There maybe hidden features in the vendor Linux related to DDR initialization and other hardware oddities that have never made main line.  Having the source to those kernels is helpful.

It seems you will never make nor modify your hardware.  Ie, you only use off the shelf hardware and never use things like *iptable/nftables*, etc., the vendor support is passable, and you (organization) are not competent in drivers/kernel programming, then it may make sense to stay put.

Otherwise, the git tools and community support can make upgrading the kernel fairly easy even with a little competency.  You may also petition the vendor to update the code if your volumes are high enough or hire a consultant to do the porting for you.  Most certainly, if you are writing custom kernel code, the merged kernels will reduce testing, coding and help with automated testings and tools.

---

If you merge the kernels, then merging the user space makes more sense.  Even though user-space can be the same code/compiler, the different Linux kernels will influence run-time behavior.  The ultimate end game is, *a merged code base is easier to support*.  The question is does the effort to get there out weight the benefits of getting there?  It depends on the project and organization.

Comment: At the very least, it would be worth some time to investigate upgrading the kernels.  You should get some estimate of the time to do this porting. 2.6.31->3.16 (or 3.18).  Also, do some investigation as there may already be support for the platform in newer kernels.  Vendors don't always make people aware of this.  Once you have the mainline, it is easier to switch hardware (maybe a 3rd cheaper board).  The vendor should at least have *tarballs* to comply with the GPL.  A recursive diff will against the same mainline version will help to tell what changes have been made.